# Is there a mod or something to remove the scale between Nether and Overworld in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

If you travel 1 Block in the Nether, you travel 8 Blocks in the overworld. Is there a way, to remove this 8:1 ratio?

Comment: Seems like it should be currently possible, by using a datapack that replaces Nether with a custom dimension with all parameters the same but with its `dimension_type` value `shrunk` set to false.

Comment: (by "currently" I mean starting 1.16-pre2)

Comment: @SF. That's an answer, not a comment.

Comment: The answer would go more in-depth, also it's an especially buggy pre-release (disabling custom dimension datpacks also disables vanilla Nether and End....), a feature 1 day old as of writing that comment, and subject to change. Plus I don't know how to go about making Nether portals link up to this custom Nether.

Answer (score -2):

So Far I have done some research and looks like nothing is possible for this to be done.

Comment: Arqade is a community collaboration site; editing other posts to make them better is one of the core pillars of the site.  We all work together to make each post the best it can be.  Because of that, there is no way to prevent anyone from editing your posts.